# notification bar in asynctask

Tags: android, android-asynctask

i have move my onCreate() to asynctask, all works well now except the notification bar, i have no idea where should i place it.  below is the functioning code:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.app_details);


    tvDescription = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDescription);

    tvTitle = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvTitle);
    tvDeveloper = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvDeveloper);

    rbRating = (RatingBar)findViewById(R.id.rbRating);

    ivLogo = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivLogo);
    ivPhoto1 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto1);
    ivPhoto2 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto2);
    ivPhoto3 = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.ivPhoto3);

    new loadPage().execute(null, null, null);               
}

public void onClickDownload(View view){
    String url = "http://www.mydomain.com/apk/" + apkURL;
    url = url.replaceAll(" ","%20");
    String sourceUrl = url;
    new DownloadFileAsync().execute(sourceUrl);
}   

private Bitmap LoadImage(String URL, BitmapFactory.Options options){       
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    InputStream in = null;
       try {
           in = OpenHttpConnection(URL);
           bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(in, null, options);
           in.close();
       } catch (IOException e1) {
       }
       return bitmap;
       }

 private InputStream OpenHttpConnection(String strURL) throws IOException{
     InputStream inputStream = null;
     URL url = new URL(strURL);
     URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();

     try{
         HttpURLConnection httpConn = (HttpURLConnection)conn;
         httpConn.setRequestMethod("GET");
         httpConn.connect();

         if (httpConn.getResponseCode() == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
             inputStream = httpConn.getInputStream();
             }
         }
     catch (Exception ex){           
     }
     return inputStream;
 }

/////start download
public class DownloadFileAsync extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
    private boolean run_do_in_background = true;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        int count;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(aurl[0]);
            URLConnection conexion = url.openConnection();
            conexion.connect();

            int lengthOfFile = conexion.getContentLength();
            Log.d("ANDRO_ASYNC", "Lenght of file: " + lengthOfFile);

            File folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/MaxApps");
            boolean success = false;
            if (!folder.exists()) {
                success = folder.mkdirs();
            }
            if (!success) {
            } else {
            }

            InputStream input = new BufferedInputStream(url.openStream());
            OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/MaxApps/" + apkURL);

            byte data[] = new byte[100*1024];

            long total = 0;

            //use try catch here to notice a disconnect             
            while ((count = input.read(data)) != -1) {
            total += count;             
            int progressPercent = (int) ((total*100)/lengthOfFile);
            if(progressPercent % 5 == 0){  //publish progress on completion of every 10%
                publishProgress(progressPercent);
                }
            output.write(data, 0, count);
            }

            output.flush();
            output.close();
            input.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {

                notificationManager.cancel(Integer.parseInt(ID.toString()));

                Notification MyN = new Notification(); MyN.icon = R.drawable.logo1;
                MyN.tickerText = "Download Failed";
                MyN.number = 1;
                MyN.setLatestEventInfo (getApplicationContext(), apkURL + " Download Failed.", "Please try again", MyPI);
                MyN.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
                MyNM.notify(1, MyN);    
                run_do_in_background = false;
            }

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {          
        notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress[0], false);
        notificationManager.notify(Integer.parseInt(ID.toString()), notification);
        }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        if(run_do_in_background) {
        notificationManager.cancel(Integer.parseInt(ID.toString()));

        Notification MyN = new Notification(); MyN.icon = R.drawable.logo1;
        MyN.tickerText = "Download Complete";
        MyN.number = 1;
        MyN.setLatestEventInfo (getApplicationContext(), "Download Complete, Click to install.", apkURL, MyPI);
        MyN.flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
        MyNM.notify(Integer.parseInt(ID.toString()) , MyN);
        }
    }
}


public class loadPage extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void> {
    private ProgressDialog pdia;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute(){
        super.onPreExecute();
        pdia = new ProgressDialog(AppDetails.this);
        pdia.setMessage("Loading...");
        pdia.show(); 
        }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(String... aurl) {
        SoapObject Request = new SoapObject (NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME);

        Request.addProperty("title", getIntent().getExtras().getString("xdaTitle"));

        SoapSerializationEnvelope soapEnvelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

        soapEnvelope.dotNet = true;
        soapEnvelope.setOutputSoapObject(Request);

        AndroidHttpTransport aht = new AndroidHttpTransport(URL);

        try
        {
            aht.call(SOAP_ACTION, soapEnvelope);
            SoapObject resultString = (SoapObject) soapEnvelope.getResponse();

            for(int i =0; i<resultString.getPropertyCount(); i++)
            {
                SoapObject array = (SoapObject) resultString .getProperty(i);

                title = array.getProperty(1).toString(); 
                description = array.getProperty(2).toString();
                developer = array.getProperty(3).toString();
                rating = array.getProperty(4).toString();
                apkURL = array.getProperty(10).toString();                  

                String logo_URL = array.getProperty(5).toString();   //get logo url

                BitmapFactory.Options bmOptions;
                bmOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmOptions.inSampleSize = 1;

                bmLogo = LoadImage(logo_URL, bmOptions);

                String photo1_URL = array.getProperty(6).toString();
                bmPhoto1 = LoadImage(photo1_URL, bmOptions);

                String photo2_URL = array.getProperty(7).toString();
                bmPhoto2 = LoadImage(photo2_URL, bmOptions);

                String photo3_URL = array.getProperty(8).toString();
                bmPhoto3 = LoadImage(photo3_URL, bmOptions);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {

        }           
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... progress) {

    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void unused) {
        tvTitle.setText(title);
        tvDeveloper.setText(developer);         

        ivLogo.setImageBitmap(bmLogo);
        ivPhoto1.setImageBitmap(bmPhoto1);
        ivPhoto2.setImageBitmap(bmPhoto2);
        ivPhoto3.setImageBitmap(bmPhoto3);

        pdia.dismiss();
    }
}
```

this is the code i wanted to use, the code will open the downloaded files, before this, it's functioning before everything moved to asynctask.

```
    MyI = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
MyI.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
MyI.setDataAndType(Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/MaxApps/" + apkURL.toString()), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");

MyPI = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, MyI, 0);
MyNM = (NotificationManager)getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), AppDetails.class);
intent.putExtra("xdaTitle", title);
final PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(), 0, intent, 0);

notification = new Notification(R.drawable.logo, "Downloading...", System.currentTimeMillis());
notification.flags = notification.flags | Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;
notification.contentView = new RemoteViews(getApplicationContext().getPackageName(), R.layout.downloadapk);
notification.contentIntent = pendingIntent;
notification.contentView.setImageViewResource(R.id.imgIcon, R.drawable.save);
notification.contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.tvText, "Downloading " + apkURL);
notification.contentView.setViewVisibility(R.id.pbStatus, View.VISIBLE);
notification.contentView.setProgressBar(R.id.pbStatus, 100, progress, false);        
notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(getApplicationContext().NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
```

ERROR:
[image]

Comment: check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11135389/android-show-notification-bar-on-downloading-application/11135489#11135489 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11339847/how-to-add-progressdialog/11339895#11339895

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i found out the solution, this is because i forgot to get the value of the ID. so when the apps wanted to create the notification, they cant create it because there is no ID. 
just add this line under doInBackground

```
 title = array.getProperty(1).toString();
```